# unknown file format on image download in php

Tags: php, image, download

i have this code for image download in php... works fine, image downloads but the problem is that it does not open in the place where it gets downloaded, and gives the error " Can't read file header...Unknown file format! "

```
<?php
$path = $row['img_url'].".jpg";
echo $path;
$filename = $path;
$ctype="application/.jpg";
// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: And what do you see if you open the downloaded file in any hex/text editor?

Comment: That `echo`, line 3? You *cannot output to the buffer* before you use `header()` (unless you're trapping it with output buffering). No whitespace, no `echo`, no `print`, no nothing. The headers you attach have to go at the *head* of the packet you're constructing (which is outputting to the buffer as "after header message content"), so they have to be set before you start building the body of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not be echoing anything before the header and try using header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

Answer (score 3):

Change the content type

```
$ctype="application/.jpg"; //It's a invalid content type
```

to

```
$ctype="image/jpeg";
```

Comment: From `@Kirtan` answer, did you remove this line `echo $path;`? Try again by removing that line.

Comment: yes i removed that echo...btw this code is actually in an include file which i have included inbetween another code...you can visit www.pdpics.com and try downloading an image of a flower...maybe ull understand what i want

Comment: and also the site has lots of images to display, and it takes long time to load, so pls suggest if any code to load images faster...thanks

Comment: Your images size are too big. Your approach is wrong. You need to scale down the images from server itself. Post it has a different question and you will get more help...

Answer (score 2):

Try using `image/jpeg` MIME type instead of `application/.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Your content type is wrong. Try to use `$ctype="image/jpeg";`